# If P1, P2, P3 are altitudes of a triangle ABC from the vertices A, B, C and is the area of the triangle, then P^-1+P^-2+P^-3 is equal to

Tags: trigonometry

If P1, P2, P3 are altitudes of a triangle ABC from the vertices A, B, C and  is the area of the triangle , then P^-1+P^-2+P^-3  is equal to

Comment: We have $\dfrac12P_1\cdot a=\triangle$ etc.


So, $\sum\dfrac1{P_1 }=\dfrac{\sum a}{2\triangle}=R\dfrac{\sum \sin A}{\triangle }$

Comment: cant able to follow @labbhattacharjee

Comment: 1/2 *base *height=area of triangle so you are saying p1= base and height =a?

Comment: rsummation sin a/triangle how

Comment: For future reference, you may take a look at 
[this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
to see how to format math on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Area of Triangle in Terms of Side and Altitude](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Triangle_in_Terms_of_Side_and_Altitude) formula,

$$\triangle=\frac12a\cdot P_1\implies\frac1{P_1}=\frac a{2\triangle}$$

$$\implies \sum\frac1{P_1}=\frac{a+b+c}{2\triangle}$$

Using [Area of Triangle in Terms of Inradius](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Triangle_in_Terms_of_Inradius) formula, $$\triangle=r\cdot s$$

where $r$ is the inradius  and $2s=a+b+c$

Comment: summation 1/p2=a+b+c/2 triangle

Comment: @burm1, $$\frac{a+b+c}2\cdot\frac1{\triangle}=s\cdot\frac1{r\cdot s}=?$$

Comment: 1/r .so 1/r+1/r+1/r =3/r

Comment: @burm1, have you noticed $\sum ?$ It should be $\dfrac1r$

Comment: yes i for get to include summation of 1/r.then summation of 3/r ?

Comment: .help me.summation of 3/r?

Comment: @burm1, It is $$\dfrac1r$$

Comment: 1/p1+1/p2+1/p3=1/r+1/r+1/r                                summation of 1/p1=1/r  then summation of 1/p2,1/p3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16693/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-burm1).

Comment: i couldn't able to chat.Its is not connecting.

Comment: i think the answer for this question  is 1/r ?

Comment: @burm1, Any doubt?

Comment: nope.its clear now.Thank you so much

Answer (score -2):

Using Area of triangle in terms of side and altitude formula, 
Triangle= 1/2 a. P1=>1/p1=a/2triangle
        => £1/p1=a+b+c/2triangle

Using Area of triangle in terms of inradius formula,
Triangle= r.s
Where r is inradius and 
2s=a+b+c
Hope it is useful......